# Lua key returning item from list as nil

Tags: lua, null, key, lua-table, unset

I have a list in lua that looks something like this:

```
list = {item1, item2, item3, etc}
```

At some point in my code, I set one of these items to nil by doing this:

```
list[2] = nil
```

Now, my problem is that whenever I try and get that value, it gets returned as nil, when I want it to return the next value in the list. For example:

```
list[2] == nil
```

instead of:

```
list[2] == item3
```

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: It seems you want to operate on a [table with a sequence](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.7). It is important that after any operation the table still has a sequence. A note on terminology: "having a sequence" is a specific condition about the contents of a table, without which certain operations would not have a useful behavior. And, "list" is a syntactical concept. (`item1, item2, item3, etc` is a list used in your table constructor.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should instead use [`table.remove`](https://devdocs.io/lua~5.3/index#pdf-table.remove) call.

```
table.remove(list, 2)
```